# How to prevent ispell from checking inside mathematical formulae

Tags: latex, auctex, spell-checking, ispell

By invoking `M-x ispell`, ispell says that 'ij' in the following formula is incorrect. How to permanently prevent ispell from this behavior.

```
$\phi_{ij}$
```

Comment: Check to make sure you're actually in a LaTeX buffer (`M-: (eq major-mode 'latex-mode)`).  `ispell` seems to ignore math environments out of the box -- at least for me, it ignores `$\phi_{ij}$` when I'm in `latex-mode`, but not when I'm in, e.g., `text-mode`.  See also [this S.O. thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121960/ispell-in-emacs-latex-mode) for more details.

Comment: @Dan the emacs on my system uses Aspell. I am in Latex-mode. The content of that link doesn't help either.

Comment: In that case, start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and try again. The behavior you request is the default in current Emacs. What's your emacs version?

Comment: @Malabarba my emacs version is "GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2014-10-24 on LEG570"

Comment: @Name In that case, start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and try again.

Comment: @Malabarba I started with emacs -Q and i have the same problem. I deleted my answer below as I realized that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Malabarba my problem was solved (see below).

Answer (score 3):

After several attempts, I found the following solution. The code uses the ideas from  [aspell - special characters and math mode](http://tex.aspcode.net/view/635399273629833626130076/aspell-special-characters-and-math-mode) and [My .emacs](http://home.thep.lu.se/~karlf/emacs.html)

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
                   (list
                    (append
                     (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) 
                     '(("[^\\]\\$" . "[^\\]\\$")))
                    (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists))) ))
```